# How to use C libraries from different path with GCC

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I am using Android NDK GCC toolchain to compile a project as command-line.
My gcc location is

```
/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
```

And I am using the gcc option

```
--sysroot=/opt/android-ndk/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/
```

There is no problem when building Hello World. But for this project, during linking, it produces the error:

```
/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld:
crtbegin_static.o: No such file: No such file or directory
```

Actually, the "crtbegin_static.o" is located in

```
/opt/android-ndk/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib
```

If I put it to

```
/opt/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3
```

then this problem can be solved.

Is there anyway to make gcc to locate the `crtbegin_static.o` correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have found the solution. It can be solved by passing the "--sysroot=" option again to the linker, not compiler only, using

```
-Wl,--sysroot=/opt/android-ndk/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a -L option which specifies the directories searched for -l.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html